# If $V:\mathbb{R}^n \to [0,\infty)$ is a continuous function such that $\lim_{n \to \infty} V(x(n)) = c \geq 0$, can we say $x(n) \to V^{-1}(c)$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I've been thinking about this problem and I was wondering if I can definitively say $x(n)$ eventually gets arbitrarily close to the set $V^{-1}(c)$. I want to emphasize that $(x(n))$ is not neccessarily a convergent sequence, but we do know $V$ is continuous and $V(x(n)) \to c \geq 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

Here, $x(n) \to V^{-1}(c)$ is defined as $\lim_{n \to \infty} \inf_{y \in V^{-1}(c)} d(x(n),y)=0$.

Comment: Maybe it’s possible a result like this is true, but your statement needs massaging. For example, take $x_n=n$ and $V\in C^\infty (\mathbb R)$, $V>0$, and $V(x)=1/x$ for $x>1$. Then $V(x_n)\to 0$ but the preimage of $0$ is empty

Comment: Even worse, I could choose the above $V$ so that $V(0)=0$, but then $\inf_{y\in V^{-1}(0)} d(x_n,y) = d(n,0)= n \to\infty$

Comment: @JackT Hm yes. Perhaps I can add the constraint that x(n) is bounded within a ball..

Comment: Yes, I think then you’ll be fine since, after passing to a subsequence, $x_n$ will converge

Comment: Interesting...hopefully I'll be able to prove this.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that $V(t) = 1+\sin\sqrt t$ and $x(n) = (\pi n)^2+1$ is a counterexample (with $c=1$).